# C program confusing from Ritchie and Kernighan

Tags: c

I have read everywhere that C is a must know language before you graduate college if you are in computer science. I have picked up the book Ritchie and Kernighan 2nd edition recommended by my professor. I am quite confused by how this program is working. If anyone could explain it that would be great! The program counts the occurrences of each digit, white spaces and other characters. I wrote comments for things I understand already and questions are added in there where I don't understand how it worked.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     int c, i, nwhite, mother;   //Declaring variables
     int ndigit[10];             //Declaring an array that holds indexes from 0-9

     nwhite = nother = 0;        //Initializes two variables to 0

     for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)    //Does this for loop keep going through and for each index
             ndigit[i] = 0;      //0-9 set the value of it to 0?

     white ((c = getchar()) !=EOF)  //While loop to check if char at EOF
     {
          if (c>='0' && c <= '9')        //Completely lost on how this works?
               ++ndigit[c - '0'];
          else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')     //Checks for white space 
               ++nwhite;
          else                                   //If nothing else increment char variable
               ++nother;

     printf("digits ");               //First for loop traverses and prints each value of
     for (i=0; i<10; ++i)             //the index. The next printf prints white space and
          printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);   //other characters
      printf(", white space = %d, other = other = %d\n", nwhite, nother);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 int ndigit[10];             //Declaring an array that holds indexes from 0-9

 for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)    //Does this for loop keep going through and for each index
```

In C arrays are indexed starting from 0, so in this case the valid indices of `ndigit` are 0 through 9, inclusive. The for loop starts from `i = 0` and increments `i` by one (`++i`) as long as `i < 10`, so the loop body gets executed for values of `i` from 0 to 9, inclusive.

In this program it is left up to the reader to figure out that the two `10` literals are the same thing; arguably it would in better style to `#define` a constant and use it in both places (but in this case it might be forgiven since the number of decimal digits is constant at 10).

```
 while ((c = getchar()) !=EOF)  //While loop to check if char at EOF
```

`getchar` returns one character read from the standard input, *or* `EOF` (which has a value distinct from any `char`) if the standard input is at end of file. There is no `EOF` character that would signal this condition.

```
      if (c>='0' && c <= '9')        //Completely lost on how this works?
```

The values of the characters for decimal digits 0 through 9 are contiguous in ASCII and most other character sets, so this code takes advantage of that and checks if `c` is equal to or greater than `'0'` *and* (`&&`) also equal to or less than `'9'`. In other words, this checks if `c` is in the range between `'0'` and `'9'`, inclusive. `'0'` and `'9'` are character literals that have integer values of the corresponding characters in the character set – this way the programmer does not have to know and write their values `if (c>=48 && c<=57)`, and the code works on incompatible character sets as long as the digit characters have contiguous values.

```
           ++ndigit[c - '0'];
```

This counts the number of times each digit occurs. Again since the characters representing the digits are contiguous, subtracting the value of the first digit (`'0'`) from the character that was read results in values 0 through 9 for the corresponding characters, which are also the valid indices of the array `ndigit` as discussed above. Of course this subtraction only works on digit characters, which is why the preceding `if` checks for that.

For example, in ASCII `'0'` has the value 48, `'1'` is 49, etc. So if `c` was `'1'`, then the result of the subtraction `c - '0'` is `'1'-'0'`, i.e., 49-48, or 1.

The `++` operator increments the value in the corresponding index of the `ndigit` array. (The first `for` loop set the initial values of in `ndigit` to zero.)

Comment: Thank you for the amazing answer! I really do appreciate it and made a lot of things clear for me. One thing I am still lost is the last part of 
++ndigit[c - '0']; 
If we follow your example does it increment the index of 1 by 1? So if we had a set of five more 1's following the initial 1 in your example the index of 1 would be a total value of 6 correct?

Comment: @user2522055 The `++` increments the value by one, i.e., the `++ndigit[c - '0']` is effectively equivalent to saying `ndigit[c - '0'] = ndigit[c - '0'] + 1`. So the value in the array `ndigit` at the index corresponding to the digit that was read is incremented.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this loops over the entire ndigit array and sets each element to 0.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)   
    ndigit[i] = 0;
```

here:

```
if (c>='0' && c <= '9')
    ++ndigit[c - '0'];
```

the condition (on the **if**-line) might be the most difficult thing to understand:

image it like this:

```
if( A and B)
    ...
```

with:

```
A = c>'0'
```

and

```
B = c<= '9'
```

that is, if `c` is between 0 and 9 (including).

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
(c >= '0' && c <= '9')        //Completely lost on how this works?
```

The `char` type in C is just an 8-bit integer, usually signed.  The correspondence between characters such as `1` and `9` and integers like 63 is defined by the [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/).  The code snipped above evaluates to 1 if `c` is a digit.  Writing `'1'` in C is equivalent to writing `49`.

Answer (score 1):

The array of integers declared is of type auto, and in C auto storage class integer array will have garbage values. Hence these are assigned with Zero.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)   
   ndigit[i] = 0;
```

For the if statement you are checking whether the given character is between 0-9. Since its getchar()- (get characters), values are compared with single quote

```
if (c>='0' && c <= '9')
```

You can also change this statement to

```
if (c>=48 && c <= 57)
```

Since ASCII **character** for '0' is 48 and '9' is 57

```
++ndigit[c - '0'];
```

You are keeping a count of numbers entered in the array, i.e lets say if input is 5 then your increasing the count of the array at index 5 by 1.

Here `c-'0'` is mentioned because,
As mentioned above ASCII character for '5' is 53.
So, the above statement results to **53 - 48 = 5**(index 5 of the array)

Comment: Thank you for your help and for clearing up many questions! Your answer is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`EOF` -  an abbreviation for `End-of-file` - is a macro defined in the `stdio.h` header file. A macro is a fragment of code which has been given a name. Wherever the name is used, it is replaced by the contents of the macro.  It is a value which represents a condition when no more characters can be read from a source, which in this case, is the `stdin` - the standard input stream, usually a keyboard. In short, for any character `c`, the condition `ch == EOF` is always false. So the following condition will keep reading from the `stdin` until you signal `EOF` by pressing `Ctrl+D` on *nix systems and `Ctrl+Z` on Windows systems:

```
white((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
}
```

Next, this condition checks whether the character read `c`, is a numeric character, i.e., a decimal digit.

```
if(c>='0' && c <= '9') {  // check if c is a numeric character.
}
```

The characters in `C` are actually integer values (think of them as `1-byte` integers) and are equal to ASCII codes of the corresponding character (though this is not mandated by the C standard). In ASCII, the code values for characters `0` through `9` are in increasing order. So, if the above condition is satisfied, then this means `c` is a numeric character.

```
++ndigit[c - '0'];
```

In the above statement, `c - '0'` is the numeric character converted to integer value. So, if the value of `c` was `'8'`, then `c - '0'` evaluates to `8`. Next, it fetches the value in the array `ndigit` at index `8`, which keeps count of the digit `8`, and increments it by `1`.